# --user-data-dir doesn't work in VSCode launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Since I wanted to use the same extensions, bookmarks, settings when debugging a Chrome app through VSCode, I wanted to have setting up `--user-data-dir` to fixate the data directory it uses.

You know, the problem is that VSCode doesn't always use the same user data directory but uses a temporary directory, and also changes occasionally the destinations, it seems.

So, simply I tried the following config.

```json
{
  "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:8011",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--disable-web-security",
    "--user-data-dir=C:\\chrome-browser"
  ],
  "runtimeExecutable": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
},
```

Opening a Chrome window, since it displays an error about the `--disable-web-security` flag, it seems it does recognize `runtimeArgs`. But it is ignoring the `"--user-data-dir=C:\\chrome-browser"` part completely.

So, what the way to deal with the issue? Thanks.

Comment: note: I also tried: with/without `C:\\\\chrome-browser`, with/without `C:/chrome-browser`, with/without `"C:/chrome-browser"`, with/without `browserConfig`.

Comment: "_You know, the problem is that VSCode doesn't always use the same user data directory but uses a temporary directory, and also changes occasionally the destinations, it seems._" can you please expand on this and give an example or multiple examples of what you have observed?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Brian De Sousa — Using a Chrome Developer Profile with Visual Studio Code Debugger](https://briandesousa1.wordpress.com/2018/05/12/using-a-chrome-developer-profile-with-visual-studio-code-debugger/).

Explain the `userDataDir` like a `launch.json` parameter, not a Chrome parameter.
I got a working copy using it like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "userDataDir": "${workspaceFolder}/profile",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser launch config types provided by the builtin [vscode-js-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug) extension support a `userDataDir` property. Its documentation reads as follows:

> By default, the browser is launched with a separate user profile in a temp folder. Use this option to override it. Set to false to launch with your default user profile. A new browser can't be launched if an instance is already running from `userDataDir`.

In case it's not clear, you can set it to a string containing a path. It seems to use NodeJS's [`path.resolve(<the path you give>)`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths), so if you don't give an absolute path, it gets interpreted relative to the extension's current working directory, which at least for me is my user home directory. At least at the time of this writing, I don't think it supports [VS Code variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

You can see related source code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/04ed65a030edb0f569d570d1554810c0df27819e/src/targets/browser/browserLauncher.ts#L98) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/04ed65a030edb0f569d570d1554810c0df27819e/src/targets/browser/edgeLauncher.ts#L137).